# Github pages link only points to README page instead of showing full site

Tags: github, deployment

I'm having an issue when deploying a web page im currently working on. When deploying via githubpages onyl shows title and README file but if i point manually to  https://soul2seul.github.io/void1/index it shows everything but the images.

This is the repository https://github.com/soul2seul/void1

I tried taking everything out of the folders as this might be confusing to where the index is, also checked misspellings in files but I still can't seem to solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove the `/` at the beginnig of each `src` of image tag. For example, write `<img src="player-of-games.jpeg" alt="grimes with knight">`  instead of `<img src="/player-of-games.jpeg" alt="grimes with knight">`. Edit all the image src in all html files.